# Duplicate files mysteriously appearing in Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive

I work with colleagues using shared google drive folders.  It works well, but sometimes one of our google docs will be duplicated.  For example, last Thursday at 6:39 pm we had at least 3 different "new" docs created by me.  They all had two new copies, and were exact copies of the 3 original files.  I did not do this on purpose, nor do I know of how this happened.

I have the Google Drive app running on my laptop, and was likely running my laptop at that time.  Could that be causing this issue?  Other colleagues have had this happen as well.  We cannot pin down what causes it, but the common element may be Google Drive offline mode.

Comment: The simplest solution have a better work flow.  Create a new document in word, save as the document to Google Drive, then save as you continue to edit.  This way you don't mistakenly create multiple files.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736141/how-to-find-duplicates-files-by-name-and-or-size-in-a-specific-folder-of-my-go

Comment: related https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/_ApOopI-Xkw